# How do I build a custom Docker image that installs MySQL and configure Jib to use it as the base image for my Java Application?

Tags: mysql, docker, google-cloud-sql, jib

Docker newbie here. I'm trying to mount a docker image of my Java App made with Jib on GCE, and hook it up to CloudSQL. However, because GCE makes the docker image use a Container-Optimized boot disk, when I SSH into the instance to try to hook it up to MySQL, I can't install mysql due to 'apt-get not found'.

I read that I could "build a custom image and configure Jib to use it as the base image" in order to have access to apt-get, but I can't seem to find any resources on how to do this.

I tried going the alpine jdk route + using apk instead of apt-get, but someone told me not to use alpine jdk as I will run into problems later.

I already have this set up in my build.gradle:

```
jib {
    from {
        image = 'order-routing-helper-image'
    }
    to {
        image = 'gcr.io/myimage'
    }
}
```

EDIT: DOCKERFILE:

```
FROM openjdk:11
VOLUME /tmp
ARG DEPENDENCY=target/dependency
COPY ${DEPENDENCY}/BOOT-INF/lib /app/lib
COPY ${DEPENDENCY}/META-INF /app/META-INF
COPY ${DEPENDENCY}/BOOT-INF/classes /app
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-cp","app:app/lib/*","com.mygroup.myapp.OrderRoutingApplication"]
```

but I don't have a order-routing-helper-image anywhere, I just know I need that line.

If I run gradle jib, and then mount the new image on GCE and SSH into it, I am able to run "sudo apt-get install mysql-client". Right now I'm getting "apt-get: not found".

Comment: can you share your dockerfile which is working for jdk?

Comment: @Adiii Added my dockerfile

Answer (score 1):

To add MySQL in Docker image, you to run the update first then add MySQL.

```
FROM openjdk:11
VOLUME /tmp
RUN apt update && apt install mysql-server -y
ARG DEPENDENCY=target/dependency
COPY ${DEPENDENCY}/BOOT-INF/lib /app/lib
COPY ${DEPENDENCY}/META-INF /app/META-INF
COPY ${DEPENDENCY}/BOOT-INF/classes /app
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-cp","app:app/lib/*","com.mygroup.myapp.OrderRoutingApplication"]
```